# MongoDb capped collection

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-ruby

can u help me pls as i surfed around but didn't find any information.
I'm working with mongoDB capped collection using Ruby. I need to update documents according to the id i retrieve from the query, but it never works.
here is the example of my code

cursor = coll.find({"EndTime" => nil})

```
begin

  while row = cursor.next_document
    if !alive row["Pid"]
      coll.update({"_id"=>row["_id"]}, { "$set" =>  { "EndTime" =>Time.now}})
    end
  end

rescue

end
```

thanx a lot

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain a bit more what it is that isn't working, it's not as if we can run your code. What does the `alive` method do, for example. Isn't it just the case that the if statement is never true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects in a capped collection are not allowed to grow. Make sure that when you insert you already have space for "EndTime" preallocated.